# Prettier onSave makes linebreak and then puts everything back inline

Tags: html, angular, format, prettier

I'm facint a prettier issue where when I save the file (angular template) prettier does its job and formats nicely the code but whenever it makes linebreaks it just puts back everything in one single line. In every element only it means when I have an in `input` or `app-custom-element` element and have multiple attributes it just puts everything in a nice format and then back to one single line.
[image]

I can see that in VSCode before the Prettier (right bottom) there is only one pipe and usually there are 2 (idk what that means).

The "printWidth" is set to 80 as default.

.prettierrc:

```
{
"printWidth": 80,
"singleQuote": true,
"useTabs": false,
"tabWidth": 2,
"semi": true,
"bracketSpacing": true
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code also? So I could test it here on my machine. The obvious answer to me would be the  printWidth, but since you already setting that I would have to check.

Comment: there is an image tagged too

Comment: Just did some tests locally and I can't get the line to break, however if I break it myself it stays broken but format everything else. Need to figure out why

Comment: Yeah my situation is similar. The line just doesn't break... But if I manually break the line and prettier is active still it puts everything back to one line. Otherwise it works fine with "not-too-long" components